# How many million people/millions of people

Tags: meaning

Which structure is correct?

> How many million people speak Spanish?
>
> How many millions of people speak Spanish?

I think I have heard either. But are both correct?

Comment: Both are correct and fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both seem reasonable.  I'd take the first to be a slightly odd question in which the speaker is asking for an exact level of imprecision (equivalent to "how many people speak Spanish, rounded to the nearest million).  The second is more loose, with "millions of" being used to stand for "large number", equivalent to "Many people speak Spanish; roughly how many?"

As the simple question "How many people speak Spanish" would be the natural way to ask the question. Your versions would be more likely to be used as rhetorical questions, meaning roughly "Wow, lots of people speak Spanish (don't you agree?)"

Comment: Nothing weird about "how many million people". [Here's an example from Nature](https://www.nature.com/nature-index/news/human-terrain-map-visualization-earth-population-data-three-dimensions), [Time magazine](https://content.time.com/time/subscriber/article/0,33009,717075,00.html), and [Hansard (UK Parliament)](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm200102/cmselect/cmtreasy/681/2030604.htm); lots of other examples online. It's often used in rhetorical questions, in embedded questions, and in general questions when you want to give a hint of the likely range (e.g. in an exam).